# curve with two minimum points

Tags: curves

how can we mathematically express a function whose the graph is a curve, like a parabola, where it has a minimum point (or maximum if opposite, it doesn't matter) BUT the minimum point is not one, but TWO points, one next to the other? is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "next to"?

Comment: that they are literaly one next to the other at x axis!

Comment: That's impossible, I'm afraid. Given any two points, no matter how close  together, there is always a point (in fact, an infinite number of points) between them.

Answer (score 2):

How about $x^4-4x^2$?  This has minima at $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: no, the one minimum must be next to the other!

Comment: @trig I think you need to be a little more clear about what you mean about "next to".  In $\mathbb{R}$, given $x\in \mathbb{R}$ there is no point $x^+$ such that $x<x^+$ but there is no $z$ such that $x<z<x^+$, so it isn't well-defined to say "literally one next to the other".